# How to periodically call to a webservice even when the app is in background?

Tags: ios, background-process

I want to do some server pulling in my iOS app. It something like this. When m app installed it should start a background service to check weather is there any new data available since the last updated date. If yeas my app should start a local push notification. How can I do this? I want to know how I can periodically check is there any new data available in server even when my app is in background. 
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: You want to start a background service after the app has been installed? that's impossible.

Comment: ok is there anything that I can achive my target?

Comment: Your server should know when there's new data and should push a remote notification. That's the iOS paradigm for this sort of background activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS 7 and above, you have Background App Refresh. It's covered in the documentation under [Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). You can read more about it under [Use Background App Refresh](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202070).

One caveat is that the user can turn off Background App Refresh for your app.